# How to get the numeric columns from DataFrame of Pyspark and calculating the zscore

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()
df = sparkSession.read.json('hdfs://localhost/abc/zscore/')
```

I am able to read the data from hdfs and I want to calculate the zscore for only numeric columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert df to Pandas and calculate zscore

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()
df = sparkSession.read.json('hdfs://localhost/SmartRegression/zscore/').toPandas()
num_cols = df._get_numeric_data().columns
results = df[num_cols].apply(zscore)
print(results)
```

Comment: `toPandas()` will try to load entire dataset in memory. This approach does not work for large datasets.

Comment: this tells you how to convert to pandas and get numeric columns from a pandas dataframe.  which may (or may not) achieve the intended outcome, but doesnt answer the question imo

Answer (score 0):

`toPandas()` does not work for big dataset as this try to load the whole dataset in driver memory.